# Can AES-CTR add values without decryption?

Tags: encryption, aes, homomorphic-encryption

I recently have studied AES cipher. On CTR mode, is it possible to add, subtract, or XOR plaintext values on encrypted data?

For example: we have an encryption of $4$ and $6$ under the same AES key, respectively denoted by $AES(4)$ and $AES(6)$.

Without decryption, can we achieve the following?

$$AES(4)⊕AES(6)=AES(4+6)$$

Where "$\oplus$" is any operation we can do over AES.

Answer (score 4):

No, with AES in CTR mode, it is not

> possible to add/subtract(or XOR?) plaintext values on encrypted data

nor define operator $\boxplus$ such that $\operatorname{AES-CTR}(4)\boxplus\operatorname{AES-CTR}(6)=\operatorname{AES-CTR}(4+6)$ that works for unknown key and plaintexts. Informally: if that worked, it would be a weakness of the encryption scheme, which would be leaking information about plaintexts from the ciphertexts.

Notice that the above notation is misleading, as the result of AES-CTR depends on 3 parameters: Key, IV and plaintext, with IV normally random (making the argument above non-rigorous). But still, even if we assume fixed IV, what's asked can't be done: it is asking an operator $\boxplus$ such that $\forall s,\forall x,\forall y, (s\oplus x)\boxplus(s\oplus y)=s\oplus(x+y)$ where $\oplus$ is XOR, and $s$ is whatever the IV encrypts to under the key considered; which is impossible.

More generally, no secure mode of operation of any secure block cipher allow homomorphic encryption.

Comment: I know that explaining this formally would be difficult, but still I think there's a big gap in your informal argument, and you should distinguish the counter-reuse case and the unique-counter case. Exposing addition is just as bad as exposing xor (for example both reveal whether a message is zero). But with counter reuse, CTR does expose xor.

Comment: @Gilles: The argument can be made rigorous for unique-counter. The one(s) for $\operatorname{AES-CTR}(x+y)$ or $\operatorname{AES-CTR}(x\oplus y)$ can't be random, and the only choice that could work reliably are this/those used for one of $\operatorname{AES-CTR}(x)$ or $\operatorname{AES-CTR}(y)$ (in the random cipher model, almost nothing can be said about how other counters would encrypt); and then almost nothing is known about whichever of $x$ or $y$ uses the other counters, which makes a suitable $\boxplus$ hopeless.